# Create a scalable Application (Desktop, Web and Restful Api) using the same language

Tags: rest, web, desktop-application

I want to start a project and thinking in advance which language is the best in order to create an Website, Desktop Application and also a RestFul API.

Let's say I want to code everything in the same language. So what is the suggestion programming language to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some time ago I was working in a similar project. I was using C# (Visual Studio IDE). In the same solution you can create diferents kind of projects (Desktop, Web and Restful Api,..); also you can add one or multiple 'dll projects' in order to share some code.

Comment: with C# I'm be able to make mobiles app?

Comment: Yes sir, you can make many kind of applications using c# https://www.quora.com/What-type-of-softwares-can-I-make-using-C

Comment: Thank you that answer gave me an idea.